# How good is the C# type inference?

Tags: c#, .net, type-inference

How good is C# type inference? I read somewhere that it's only for local variables? Does it work for class level attributes? For method signatures? Method return types? etc.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are a few main kinds of type inference in C#:

- Implicitly typed local variables:

  - Only for local variables
  - Only when the value is assigned as part of the declaration
  - Value cannot be null
  - Value cannot be a lambda expression, anonymous method or method group (without a cast)
  - The compile-time type of the value is used for the type of the variable
  - Any further uses of the variable are only checked against the type determined by the initial declaration+assignment; they don't contribute to the inference itself.
- Generic method type argument inference, i.e. you don't specify the type arguments in a call to a generic method, the compiler figures them out based on the arguments.

  - Would be really handy to have this for generic types as well as generic methods
  - Really handy anyway - LINQ would be hard or impossible to use without it
  - Anonymous types would be fairly useless without it
  - Really complicated rules, even the spec is wrong in a few places
- Lambda expression parameter type inference

  - Compiler tries to work out the types of the parameters for lambda expressions based on the context in which it's used
  - Usually works pretty well, in my experience
- Array type inference, e.g. `new[] { "Hi", "there" }` instead of `new string[] { "Hi", "there" }`

  - Various small restrictions, nothing major

I've probably forgotten some other features which might be called "type inference". I suspect you're mostly interested in the first, but the others might be relevant to you too :)

Answer (score 8):

It can only be used for local variables, but it can detect the type in many different forms.

```cs
var myVar = SomeMethodThatReturnsInt(); // `myVar` will be deduced as an `int`.
var myIntList = new List<int>(); // `myIntList` will be deduced as a List<int>.
var myOwnVar = new { Name = "John", Age = 100 }; // `myOwnVar` will be deduced as an AnonymousType.
```

> Notice: When you work with anonymous types, you **must** declare variable with `var`.

Another example of Type Inference with Lambda expressions:

```cs
var myList = new List<int>();
// <add values to list>
int x = myList.Find(i => i == 5); // `i` will be deduced as an `int`.
```

Comment: Why the second example is not technically type inference?

Comment: +1 to Rafa Castaneda. Why is the second example not an example of type inference? it certainly looks like it to me!

Answer (score 1):

It works only with local variables as I understand it.